# How to update a URL in PHP?

Tags: php

I have the current url as:
http://example.com/abcdef

When an event occurs (clicking submit button etc.), the current url needs to be updated with a different value other than "abcdef". For example,
http://example.com/xaxaxa

"xaxaxa" is stored in a variable in PHP (basically from mySQL).

I know how to "get" (using $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']) the current url in php, but can anyone tell how do I "set" one. I dont want to actually redirect to another page (e.g. using Location:..). I just need the url to be updated.

Answer (score 3):

Cannot be done using PHP, which runs at the server-end. Use JavaScript/HTML5 for this.
See **[location.hash](http://www.ezineasp.net/post/Javascript-Location-Hash-with-Example.aspx)** and **[history.pushState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history/)**

Comment: Cant you use .htaccess RewriteEngine in some way/form?

Comment: But that would still require that the URL change somehow, to trigger the rewrite rule. That is possible only with a server-postback and the OP isn't ready to do that with `location: ... `

Comment: Would you be able to show me an example in Javascript..if not, a link to a similar resource would be great as well. thanks.

Comment: See some of the answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page).

Comment: Also, this is a brilliant tutorial to walk you through the html5 history api -> http://spoiledmilk.com/blog/html5-changing-the-browser-url-without-refreshing-page

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the HTML5 history API.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history/

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with HTAccess to route the page properly, example code;

`RewriteEngine on`

`#Force redirect for 404 errors to /index.php`

`RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`

`RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`

`RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l`

`RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /index.php [L,QSA]`

For the other issue, you'll need to update the links to include the new location in the URL.

Comment: This will still require a server-postback, or the htaccess rewrite-rule won't kick in.